# Replace datetime column in DF with hour from int column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark df with an hour column (int) like this:

| hour |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| ... |
| 14 |

And I have an `execution_datetime` variable that looks like `2022-01-02 17:23:11`

Now I want to calculate a new column for my DF that holds my `execution_datetime` but the hour is replaced by the values from the hour col. Output should look like:

| hour | exec_dttm_with_hour |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-02 00:23:11 |
| 0 | 2022-01-02 00:23:11 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 01:23:11 |
| ... | ... |
| 14 | 2022-01-02 14:23:11 |

I know there are ways using i.e. `.collect()`, then edit the list and insert as new col. But I need to make use of sparks parallel execution since it could be a super high data load. Also, casting it to pandas and then editing it is not suitable for my use case.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`make_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#make_timestamp) function if you're on spark 3+, else you can use an UDF.

```py
spark.range(15). \
    withColumnRenamed('id', 'hour'). \
    withColumn('static_dttm', func.lit(execution_datetime).cast('timestamp')). \
    withColumn('dttm',
               func.expr('''make_timestamp(year(static_dttm), 
                                           month(static_dttm), 
                                           day(static_dttm), 
                                           hour, 
                                           minute(static_dttm), 
                                           second(static_dttm)
                                           )
                         ''')
               ). \
    drop('static_dttm'). \
    show()

# +----+-------------------+
# |hour|               dttm|
# +----+-------------------+
# |   0|2022-01-02 00:23:11|
# |   1|2022-01-02 01:23:11|
# |   2|2022-01-02 02:23:11|
# |   3|2022-01-02 03:23:11|
# |   4|2022-01-02 04:23:11|
# |   5|2022-01-02 05:23:11|
# |   6|2022-01-02 06:23:11|
# |   7|2022-01-02 07:23:11|
# |   8|2022-01-02 08:23:11|
# |   9|2022-01-02 09:23:11|
# |  10|2022-01-02 10:23:11|
# |  11|2022-01-02 11:23:11|
# |  12|2022-01-02 12:23:11|
# |  13|2022-01-02 13:23:11|
# |  14|2022-01-02 14:23:11|
# +----+-------------------+
```

Using UDF

```py
def update_ts(string_ts, hour_col):
    import datetime

    dttm = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    return datetime.datetime(dttm.year, dttm.month, dttm.day, hour_col, dttm.minute, dttm.second)

update_ts_udf = func.udf(update_ts, TimestampType())

spark.range(15). \
    withColumnRenamed('id', 'hour'). \
    withColumn('dttm', update_ts_udf(func.lit(execution_datetime), func.col('hour'))). \
    show()

# +----+-------------------+
# |hour|               dttm|
# +----+-------------------+
# |   0|2022-01-02 00:23:11|
# |   1|2022-01-02 01:23:11|
# |   2|2022-01-02 02:23:11|
# |   3|2022-01-02 03:23:11|
# |   4|2022-01-02 04:23:11|
# |   5|2022-01-02 05:23:11|
# |   6|2022-01-02 06:23:11|
# |   7|2022-01-02 07:23:11|
# |   8|2022-01-02 08:23:11|
# |   9|2022-01-02 09:23:11|
# |  10|2022-01-02 10:23:11|
# |  11|2022-01-02 11:23:11|
# |  12|2022-01-02 12:23:11|
# |  13|2022-01-02 13:23:11|
# |  14|2022-01-02 14:23:11|
# +----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` to connect multiple strings in a row and `lit` to add a constant value to each row.

In the following code, a new column `timestamp` is introduced where the first 11 characters of `execution_datetime` are conceited with characters after the hours and in between the hours are added. It also makes sure, that the hours have a leading zero.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.withColumn('timestamp', f.concat(f.lit(execution_datetime [0:11]), f.lpad(f.col('hour'), 2, '0') , f.lit(f.lit(execution_datetime [13:]))))
```

*Remark: This might be the faster version than using timestamp functions as suggested in samkart's answer, but also less safe in catching wrong inputs.*